# How on Mac OS use .localhost instead on .dev in Chrome by dnsmasq

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macos-mojave, dnsmasq

I installed by this instruction https://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/ `.dev` support local domain.
When I replaced all configs to `localhost` instead of `dev` I can't open my `some.localhost` domain.

In console I successfully checked `some.localhost` domain for working:

```
bash-3.2$ ping -c 1 some.localhost
PING some.localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
```

But in chrome I have a CONNECTION_REFUSED error yet.
Help me please.

Comment: You installed a program so you don't have to edit your hosts file for developing? Have you tried stopping dnsmasq to see if it works? The page has two options on configuration, did you do number two?

Comment: Why would you replace dev with localhost in configs of dnsmasq?